# SQL Server Clustering for HA combined with Log Shipping for DR

Tags: sql-server, logs, clustering

Has anyone implemented SQL Server log shipping in a clustered environment? Are there any issues or things to consider when implementing this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

In general, log shipping works same way whether SQL server is clustered or not. Only thing you need to use **windowsclustername\Share** when you copy your logs instead of specifying node names e.g. nodel1\share  or node22\share so it works regardless what node your SQL serve is running.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering can coexist only with mirroring . The clustering cannot coexist with log shipping. The following article described what high availability solutions can coexist https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500117(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Because links are subject to being moved or deleted, it would be better to add a brief synopsis to better explain your answer.

Comment: I would consider the article you linked to as "incomplete".  Log Shipping is very much compatible with Failover Clustered Instances so long as you setup the share as @SQLLearner points out above.  That MSDN article seems to be based off of this [MS Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/beatrice_popa/2013/05/10/sql-server-clustering-and-mirroringlog-shipping/), where [Shanky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/42379/shanky) even points out this discrepancy.